# running metabat2 and checkM with snakemake

Tags: snakemake

Hi I have been trying to put metabat2 and checkm in my pipeline to see which bacteria in my sample but I keep running in to an error with snakema. My snakemake code is

```
rule all:
    input:
        [f"nanoplot_out/" for sample in samples],
    [f"zipped/zipped.gz" for sample in samples],    
    [f"filtered/nanofilt_out.gz" for sample in samples],
    [f"unzipped/read.fastq" for sample in samples],
    [f"assembled/" for sample in samples],
    [f"nanopolish/assembly.fasta" for sample in samples],
[f"medaka_consensus/" for sample in samples],
    [f"input/consensus.fasta" for sample in samples],
    [f"output_antismash/" for sample in samples],
    [f"metabat2/bin" for sample in samples],
    [f"metabat2/CheckM.txt" for sample in samples]
rule metabat2:
    input:
        "medaka_consensus/consensus.fasta"
    output:
        directory("metabat2/")
    conda:
        "envs/metabat2.yaml"
    shell:
        "metabat2 -i {input} -o {output} -v"

rule checkM:
    input:
        "metabat2/"
    output:
        "metabat2/CheckM.txt"
    conda:
        "envs/metabat2.yaml"
    shell:
        "checkm lineage_wf -f {output} -t 30 -x fa {input}"
```

and my error message is `MissingInputException in line 4 of /home/ec2-user/snakemake_JHB-2-14-20_uncor_polish_anti5_meta/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule all:
metabat2/bin`

Is there anyone that could help me to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is stating that snakemake could not find any rule that can create the file (or directory?) `metabat2/bin`. Assuming it gets created by the rule `metabat2`, you will need to add it as part of `output`.

```
rule metabat2:
    input:
        "medaka_consensus/consensus.fasta"
    output:
        a = metabat2/bin
        b = directory("metabat2/")
    conda:
        "envs/metabat2.yaml"
    shell:
        "metabat2 -i {input} -o {output.b} -v"
```